# How to create a dynamic table in angular2?

Tags: angular

## Aravind

Rows

Columns

Submit 
 Reset

Comment: You should at-least post some of your code what have you done so far

Comment: Will add next time. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in directive ****ngFor*** in angular2.0.

```
 <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let x of names">
          <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
          <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you should add it 'template:' section in respective @Component()

Comment: 1. created main.ts -> AppComponent
 2. In AppComponent -> aravind-form
 3. aravind-form-component -> Declared variables and used templateURL
 4. aravind.form.component.html -> created rows text box and columns text and submit button.

My question: users will keyin no of rows, columns. 
when click submit it should display table based on the no of rows,columns entered by the user ?

Comment: sure, i will help you

Comment: how to write for loops (two , one followed by another)

Comment: <table border="1">
<tr *ngFor = " let x of noofrows">
 <td>{{x}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: export class AppComponent {
 public noofrows:array;
 public noofcols:array;
 
 constructor()
 {
  console.clear();
  this.noofrows=[2];
  this.noofcols=[4];
 }